# Horizontal (sub)pixel gaps in element with clip-path

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, opera

I have a SVG clip path which I apply to an element containing several other elements. If any of these child elements create a new stacking context, e.g. through `transform: translateZ(0)`, I get horizontal (sub)pixel gaps – see image.

This happens in Chrome and Opera on MacOS and only on certain viewport heights.

Is there a way to remedy this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hg6Ldejk/1/) of the issue. Try resizing the preview pane vertically.

[image: bug in chrome]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug. You can fix it by adding a tiny bit to the `clip-path` values using `calc()`. For example if you're using `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);` you can change it to `clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% calc(100% + 0.5px), 100% calc(100% + 0.5px));` and that should remove the bottom gap.